# MATLAB, recover a signal that has a cosinusoidal interference and that has been AM modulated

Tags: matlab, filters, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, filtering

I have a signal which has been AM modulated but the channel also added a cosinusoidal interference `A cos(2 * Pi * f0 * n * Tc + Phase)`, at the same `f0` frequency of modulation. `Tc` is the sampling period.

[image]

I am given the distorted signal `x(nTc)` and I need to recover the original signal `v(nTc)`

I also have the filter coefficients of two filters:

A) a notch filter centered at `16KHz`;

B) a low pass filter;

I started by calculating the fft of `x(nTc)` and it has a big peak at `7500 Hz`, which is my `f0`
Now I need to eliminate the cosinusoidal interference and the notch filter seems to be the right way to do it but it is centered at `16KHz`, so I have to center it at `7500Hz`. To do so I used this Fourier transform property: `exp(j * w0 * n)x(n) -> X(j(w-w0))`. In my case I need to multiply the filter coefficients of the notch filter by `exp(j * 2 * Pi * 8500 * n * Tc)`
Everything should be good, so now I can filter the `x(nTc)` signal using `input_without_interference = filtfilt(notch_coeff,1,x(nTc))`

At this point I have to AM demodulate the signal. Demodulation is accomplished by multiplying the signal by the same carrier that modulated it, in this case `cos(2 * Pi * f0 * n * Tc)`
To do so I used this code:

```
for k=0:length(input_without_interference))-1
    dem_signal(k+1) = cos(2 * Pi * 7500 * k * Tc) * input_without_interference(k+1);
end
```

Now If I plot the signal `dem_signal` it still shows some traces of modulation so something is certainly wrong.

Assuming everything went good, I now have many replicas of the original signal `v(nTc)` and one of them is centered in the origin, so to take it I just need to use the low pass filter. `v(nTc) = filtfilt(lowpass,1,dem_signal)`

Result: the output is still distorted and it has an imaginary component! Where is my
 mistake?

Comment: Could you share your entire script? Also, is this homework? Note that it's not surprising that your result would have an imaginary component, because the coefficients of your frequency-shifted notch filter are complex.

Comment: I agree with Jason R.  You're causing problems for yourself by using a filter with complex-valued coefficients.  I suggest you discard that notch filter centered at 16 kHz altogether and use a real-coefficient, narrowband, notch filter whose center freq is 7.5 kHz.Another option is to reduce the magnitude of the

Comment: I suggest you discard that notch filter centered at 16 kHz altogether and use a real-coefficient, narrowband, notch filter whose center freq is 7.5 kHz.  Another option is to modify x(nTc)'s FFT spectral samples by reducing the magnitude of the "big" +7.5 kHz spectral component (as well as reduce the magnitude of the "big" -7.5 kHz spectral component) and then perform an inverse FFT.  Doing that will produce time-domain samples.  Next, perform your demodulation process on the real part of your time-domain samples.